# How to train/update neural networks faster without a decrease in performance?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, training, efficiency

I noticed that there are many studies in recent years on how to train/update neural networks faster/quicker with equal or better performance. I find the following methods(except the chips arms race):

1. using few-shot learning, for instance, pre-taining and etc.
2. using the [minimum viable dataset](https://medium.com/appanion/the-minimum-viable-data-set-5deb45524726), for instance using [(guided) progressive sampling](https://bmsce.ac.in/conferences/CS/PID5919853.pdf).
3. model compression, for instance, [efficent transformers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06732.pdf)
4. [Data echoing](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/05/speeding-up-neural-network-training.html), or simply put let the data pass multiple times in the graph(or GPU)

Is there a systematic structure on this topic and how can we update or train a model faster without loss of its capacity?

Comment: use validation set maybe?

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by validation set? I cannot get your point, sorry. Could you please flesh your comment out into an answer?

Comment: Use val data to check if you are overfitting (in addition to other tricks), this will prevent the degradation of the model's performance

Comment: @Alex Yes, but let's consider the model that takes N epochs to get the best performance over the develop set, can we speed the training by other methods? Make the N smaller than that for the original model or less time? For instance by reducing the amount of training data or compressing the model size?

Comment: what do you mean by 'compressing the model size'?

Comment: @Alex Yes, using techniques like knowledge distilling or pruning and etc.